# Changing restitution on contact/collision not effected immediately

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit

I have one object that collides with two other objects. I change restitution based on the collided objects in question. Whenever the restitution changes from 0.5 to 0 it isn't recognized immediately, this causes bounciness for a short while when the restitution is suppose to be zero. How can I make the change recognizable/effected immediately? Please see my code below:

```
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask  {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }
    else    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }



    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == spriteCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory1  {

        var spriteContactNode = firstBody.node
        spriteContactNode?.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.5
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -2.0)
    }

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == spriteCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory2  {

        var spriteContactNode = firstBody.node
        spriteContactNode?.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -0.5)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you're trying to do will work.  Restitution affects a period of time, like if the node had an action that was repeated a few times.

Try changing the nodes `isDynamic` property to false instead.

```
var spriteContactNode = firstBody.node
spriteContactNode?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
spriteContactNode?.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -0.5)
spriteContactNode?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
```

Then setting it back to true may be enough to let bounce only once before falling with the gravity.